# Greetings Sibling. Verily

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, humor

I encouraged my sibling to continue exploring the world. I impressed upon my other sibling that, while friends are commendable, family is what really counts. I offered them both assistance should they get into a spot of bother.

I contemplated the possibility that they no longer trusted one another; or relied on their mutual affection.

Two hypothetical inquiries were made to test the boundaries of my offer to help. The first contemplated the possibility that one of the siblings had traveled to a remote location. I assured them that the telephone would still work. The second considered the other sibling becoming bankrupt. Again, I was able to comfort them with my offer of continued support.

The conversation continued in this manner for a while.

> Who and where am I?

Comment: Can this be tied to mythology? I have an idea, but I'm not sure if it is valid or not.

Comment: I'm going to wait a bit before I give out clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are Avicii in the song "Hey Brother" in which the following lyrics appear.

> What if I'm far from home?
>   Oh brother, I will hear you call!
>   What if I lose it all?
>   Oh sister, I will help you hang on!
>   Oh, if the sky comes falling down, for you
>   There's nothing in this world I wouldn't do

Clearly your two inquiries are there (one of the siblings had traveled to a remote location and the other sibling becoming bankrupt) with continued assurances of support.

Edit:
Additionally your first paragraph matches the first verse of the song

> Hey brother! There's an endless road to rediscover
>   Hey sister! Know the water's sweet but blood is thicker
>   Oh, if the sky comes falling down, for you
>   There's nothing in this world I wouldn't do

Edit 2:
Arguably you are Dan Tyminski, who provided the vocal track for the song, but that is probably nit-picky

Comment: Great job! Hope you enjoyed it!

Comment: I did, and it had the added benefit of being a song I quite like but hadn't listened to in a while so now I get to go listen to it and enjoy it again

Comment: @DrXorile now i understand the source of my confusion, this song is also `obviously` about quantum entanglement.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps

> Quantum Entanglement?, or perhaps a source of entangled particles

It seems to me that

> Your siblings are 2 entangled particles. You're undergoing an experiment if quantum entanglement holds. Perhaps some sort of EPR-experiment. The 2 hypothetical inquires are the measurements being done on the entangled particles. The telephone still works is related to the 'connection' between the particles. I'm guessing that the bankrupt inquiry is a measurement of spin (- for bankrupt)

Might be farfetched/wrong, but came to mind immediately upon reading the riddle.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is also not right!

Comment: @DrXorile Figured it might not be, but it fit quite well. I'll have to sleep on what it might be ;)

Comment: I'm always amazed and impressed by the connections people are able to make!

Comment: @DrXorile May be because your question always have multiple answers. :p

Comment: A fair point! Although this is the first riddle of this type that I've done.

Answer (score 1):

I seems too obvious, but I think that this person is a close relative (brother/sister/parent)
Reason: "I encouraged my sibling to continue exploring the world. I impressed upon my other sibling that, while friends are commendable, family is what really counts." The clear and repeated use of the word sibling, in reference to the other 2 people suggests that they are all 3 siblings.

This person is likely sitting at home on a telephone call/conference call, calling each of the siblings/relatives.
Reason: The first sibling was encouraged to "continue exploring", suggesting that the travel was a current and ongoing activity. Further on the query asks about the possibility that the sibling had travelled to a remote location, suggesting that the sibling is not physically present with the person talking, but is somewhere else. The fact that they are talking means they are on the phone or some similar communication device. Reference "telephone would still work".

Comment: Given that the question is tagged as a riddle, I would expect that the answer would be more obtuse than just a literal interpretation of the text. In this case, the most likely solution would be that the word sibling is not used in it's classical / literal sense. For instance, [here's a riddle](http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?op=2&id=19118&comm=0) about "siblings" that refers to the Great Lakes in North America. Try to think beyond the literal text and find some other meaning.

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Is this some kind of

> Solar System

**Reasons**

> There is the 'subject' = sun in the solar system
>  two siblings = two planets
>  friends of the siblings = satellite of the planets

I encouraged my sibling to continue exploring the world. I impressed upon my other sibling that, while friends are commendable, family is what really counts. I offered them both assistance should they get into a spot of bother.

> One planet doesn't orbit the sun anymore and other has many satellites. Here offering assistance means that they will still be in the gravitational affect of the sun.

I contemplated the possibility that they no longer trusted one another; or relied on their mutual affection.

> There is very less affect of gravity of a planet to the other.

The first contemplated the possibility that one of the siblings had traveled to a remote location. I assured them that the telephone would still work.

> One planet has gone too far of solar system but the gravitational force still works.

The second considered the other sibling becoming bankrupt. Again, I was able to comfort them with my offer of continued support.

> Only possible meaning is that the other planet is destroyed but it will still orbit the sun.

The conversation continued in this manner for a while.

> This kept on going.

**FINAL ANSWER**

> You are 'Sun' at the 'center of the solar system'

Comment: Nice try,, but it is not correct!